# Macbook locked with icloud

Tags: macos, icloud, find-my-mac

So I was playing around with the findmymac/iphone app just testing it out and hit the "lock" option. My Macbook Pro is now locked, which has been fine up until this point because I just hit "option" on startup enter my passcode and I'm in. The problem now is I'm wanting to reformat my macbook so I can partition it (need to for work) but obviously I cant because the lock mode inhibits me from doing so. I cant find any help on this issue, my situation seems a bit different because most people asking the questions seem to not have their passcode but I have mine, is there a really obvious fix that I am missing?

Answer (score 2):

After locking a Mac with iCloud, a normal reboot (no Option or other modifier keys) should take you to an unlock screen. Enter the PIN there, and it should fully unlock the Mac (unlike entering the PIN after holding Option, which just temporarily bypasses the lock). Is this now working on your Mac?

Comment: if I start it without holding option, I get the blinking question mark as if there is no hard drive

Comment: When you boot with Option and enter the PIN, does the Recovery HD volume appear as a choice? If so, try selecting that, and see if you get the unlock screen. If that doesn't work, can you select the regular startup volume in System Preferences -> Startup Disk pane?

Comment: That did the trick! thanks! Didnt even think to do that